# Draw images on CGContext without initWithFrame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, cgcontext

I currently have an `UIImage` object which gets initialized with `initWithFrame` and then I have some 2D drawings in `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{}` with `CGContext. Very basic. All I want to know is, how can I draw through the push of e.g. a button or any event (not only on initialization)?

I tried copying the code inside `drawRect` to a new method called `redraw` but this results in an obvious error:

> **CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0**

I only want to know how to be able to draw through CGContext while the UIView has been created. *Not e.g. how to listen for an UIButton event*

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only draw inside a UIView's `drawRect:` method or by creating your own *image* context. You cannot draw to the screen by any means other than `drawRect:` or implementing drawing for a CALayer. You need to set variables on your view accordingly, then call `setNeedsDisplay` to have it redrawn. For example, add a property `@property(retain) UIImage *image;` to your view, set the new image on it and then call `setNeedsDisplay` (or even better, implement the `setImage:` method and call `[self setNeedsDisplay];` here).

Comment: If I frequently (100hz) need to draw a new rect (only a single colored rectangle), would this then still be an option or what alternative should I rather use? (CGContext does what I need - except the redraw)

Comment: AFAIK the iPhone's screen only has a refresh rate of 60Hz. Anyway, if you need to draw this often you need to get familiar with CoreAnimation and use the [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009031).